# Get elements of a given class under a certain div and get each value

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am trying to **get the input values off a form and set them as object properties**.
Inside the form there are two divs, one for contact1 details and other for contact2.

To solve the problem I created a javascript object "**ContactTab()**" with its properties, then I created two instances of it "**contact1**" and "**contact2**" and also a method "**setName()**" to set the name.

Finally I wrote the method "populateContactTab("divID")" which aims to populate "contact1" or "contact2" depending on the div specified in the function.

I am not getting any errors but when I output an instance object  the name is empty.

should i be doing this differently?

Thank you.

### HTML

```
<form id="jform" action="" method="get">
  <div id="primaryContact" style="float:left;">
        <label for="jname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="jname" class="contactTab jname" name="fname" value=""><br>

   </div>
   <div id="secondaryContact" style="float:right;">
        <label for="jname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="jname" class="contactTab jname" name="fname" value=""><br>            
    </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function ContactTab() // I specify the object
{
    this.name = "";
    this.lastName = "";
    this.address = "";
    this.age = "";
    this.phone = "";
}
var contact1 = new ContactTab();//Create two instances
var contact2 = new ContactTab();    

function populateContactTab(divID){ //should get values of inputs of specific class and set them to one of the instances.

    event.preventDefault();

    var objectName; 
    if (divID == "primaryContact")
    { 
        objectName = "contact1";
    }
    else (divID == "secondaryContact") 
    {  
        objectName = "contact2";
    }


    $(".contactTab").each( function(index, item){
        switch(item) 
        {
        case $(this).hasClass('jname'):
            objectName.setName($(this).val()); 
        case 'jlastName':
            objectName.setLastName();     
        case 'jage':
            objectName.setAge();      
        case 'jphone':
            objectName.setPhone();
        case 'jaddress':
            objectName.setAddress();
            break;

        }
    });

}

ContactTab.prototype.setName = function(newName)
{
    if (typeof newName != 'undefined')
    {
        this.name = newName;
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("Please enter a valid name");
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be easier if you gave the controls unique names ie. Contact_1_firstname and Contact_2_firstname. More typing but less code in the long term. Also, ids have to be unique to the page.

Comment: Hi jeff thanks for your help, do you mean controls as the object properties? Or as id's in the HTML? thanks.

Comment: You should be setting `objectName` to the object, not the object's name.

Comment: He means the IDs in the HTML: you can't have two `id="jname"` elements.

Comment: Hi Barmar thanks for your help, if you mean var objectName; 
`if (divID == "primaryContact")
    { 
        objectName = "contact1";
    }
else (divID == "secondaryContact") 
    {  
        objectName = "contact2";
    }**objectName.setName($(this).val());**`, I am trying to set it to contact1 object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems.

First, you should assign the objects, not their names:

```
if (divID == "primaryContact")
    { 
        objectName = contact1;
    }
else if (divID == "secondaryContact") 
    {  
        objectName = contact2;
    }
```

You were also missing an `if` after `else`.

Second, you need to restrict your `.each()` loop to just the DIV you were given to process:

```
$("#"+divID).find(".contactTab").each(...);
```

Third, you can't use `switch` the way you are, it should be a series of `if`s:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("jname")) {
    objectName.setName($(this).val());
} else if ($(this).hasClass("jlastName")) {
    objectName.setLastName($(this).val());
} else if ($(this).hasClass("jage")) {
    objectName.setAge($(this).val());
} ...
```

`switch` is just for comparing a value against a series of literals, but `item` in your case is a jQuery element, not a class name.

Finally, as noted in the comments, you need to make the `id` attributes of all your elements unique, so you can't reuse `id="jname"` as you did.

Comment: Just made those changes, for some reason I am getting an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Object contact1 has no method 'setName' ".  I declared the method as can be seen at the bottom of the javascript section of my question. Why doesn't it work? Contact one is an instance of ContactTab, shouldn't it inherit it?

Comment: I don't think you correctly made the first change, that's the error I get if I assign strings.

Comment: When assigning an object as opposed to a string, how do you do it? I have " objectName = contact1;" where contact1 is the name of my object.

Comment: You do it exactly as I wrote in the answer.